# Flutter firebase query snapshot error: "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Fetching document with required field value, but this doesn't work

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('orders')
            .where("id", isEqualTo: orderList[index].id)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) {
          snapshot.docs.first.reference.update({"status": 'Rejected'});
          print("yes");
        });
```

But this works

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .where("id", isEqualTo: orderList[index].id)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      //snapshot.docs.first.reference.update({"status": 'Rejected'});
      print("yes");
    });
```

Error

> E/flutter (10845): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element

Answer (score 2):

The QuerySnapshot object returned by a query can return 0 or more DocumentSnapshot objects.  You should check to see if there are more then 0 before indexing into the `docs` array.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('orders')
    .where("id", isEqualTo: orderList[index].id)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
        snapshot.docs.first.reference.update({"status": 'Rejected'});
      }
      else {
        // Figure out what you want to do if the list is empty.
        // This means your query matched no documents.
      }
    });
```

Comment: Value is not updating in cloud firestore

Comment: If you have a new problem, post a new question and explain what isn't working the way you expect, along with your debugging information.  Be sure you are logging everything and checking for errors.